# Finding convergence using Integral or Comparison test

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

question:

I have the series: $\left\{ne^{-n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

How should I apply the integral test to determine if the above series is convergent?

I know this function is:
positive and continuous on $[1,\infty]$

I took the derivative of $f(x)=xe^{-x}$ and found it's montone/decreasing, so integral test is applicable.

I set up integral from $1$ to $\infty$ of $(xe^{-x})$

$u = x du = dx$

$v = -e^{-x} dv = e^{-x}$

$-xe^{-x} + \int e^{-x}$

$-xe^{-x} - e^{-x} = -e^{-x} (x + 1)$

evaluating from $1$ to $t$:

$ -(1/e^t) (t+1) + 2/e^{1} $

But when I do $\lim_{t\to\infty} [-(1/e^t) (t+1)]$ it should $= \frac {\infty}{\infty}$, which would mean $ a_n $ would be divergent, but it is convergent.

Does anyone know where my mistake is??

Thanks!

Comment: please learn to typeset the math properly

Answer (score 0):

If you use L'hospitals rule on $\lim_{t\to\infty} -\dfrac{t+1}{e^t}$, you get $\lim_{t\to\infty} -\dfrac{1}{e^t}= 0$, hence the series converges

Alternatively, you can use Ratio test, and you have $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{a^{n+1}}{a^n} = \lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{n+1}{n}\cdot \dfrac{e^{-n-1}}{e^{-n}} = \lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\cdot \dfrac{1}{e} = \dfrac{1}{e}<1$$

Hence the series converges by ratio test

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've made sure that those conditions are met and you can use the integral test, here is how you would do the integral. You're essentially just trying to take the integral $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{1}^{b}xe^{-x}dx$. So, use integration by parts with $u=x\implies du=dx$ and $dv=e^{-x}dx\implies v=-e^{-x}$ to get $$uv-\int vdu=\lim_{b\to\infty}-xe^{-x}\bigg\vert_{1}^{b}-\int_{1}^{b} (-e^{-x})dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\dfrac{-b}{e^{b}}-(-e^{-1})-e^{-x}\bigg\vert_{1}^{b}=0+e^{-1}-\left(\lim_{b\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{e^b}-\frac{1}{e^1}\right)=2e^{-1}$$
Notice that the limit, when we get indeterminate forms like $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, then we can use L'Hopital's Rule (google it if you're not sure: $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\dfrac{-x-1}{e^{x}}\to\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}\implies \lim_{b\to\infty}\dfrac{-x-1}{e^{x}}\underbrace{=}_{\text{by L'Hopital's Rule}}\lim_{b\to\infty}\dfrac{(-x-1)'}{(e^{x})'}=\lim_{b\to\infty}\dfrac{-1}{e^x}=0$$